# Adding # before a div id without creating an HTMLDivElement

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array of div names (with no hash), and i'm using the following jQuery code do do something with them:

```
for(dayList in dayLists) {
  dayListID = "#" + dayList;
  $(dayListID).append("test");
}
```

Unfortunately, it does not work. I can see in the console that `dayListID` is an "HTMLDivElement", rather than the string that JQ is expecting. How can I join a hash and the div name while keeping the result as a string? Thanks!

Comment: dayList is a string, not a HTMLDivElement. Sorry if the question was kind confusing.

Comment: Can you please show how did you get the `dayLists` array?

Comment: Show us the rest of the code. I'm guessing that the problem is that you have an array of divs instead of an array of strings.

Comment: With `dayLists = ["something", "somethingElse"]`

Comment: The for loop is not doing what you think it is, see this example: http://jsfiddle.net/GBteY/

Comment: When I show `dayLists` in the console, they are strings: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/40837996/Screenshots/zqpo.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
for(dayList in dayLists) {
  dayListID = "#" + dayLists[dayList];
  $(dayListID).append("test");
}
```

`dayList` in `for .. in` is not a i-th value of the `dayLists`, but it is the index. So for array `["one", "two"]` variable `dayList` is `0, 1` and to get the values you must use `dayLists[dayList]`.

As *Matt* wrote in the comments it is good to use `hasOwnProperty` to make sure the properties we are looping through are the objects own.

```
for(dayList in dayLists) {
  if(dayLists.hasOwnProperty(dayList) {
    dayListID = "#" + dayLists[dayList];
    $(dayListID).append("test");
  }
}
```

*... and then you realize the standard simple `for` loop (answer by MДΓΓ БДLL) is actually a better idea. The standard `for` is also faster.*

See details **[HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4261096/1011582)**.

Comment: You should really use `hasOwnProperty` in that loop, as you'll iterate over a lot of other junk that you don't want/care about.

Comment: Much better to just use [the right tool for the job](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for).

Comment: @MДΓΓБДLL Indeed. I was updating my answer to mention benefits of the simple `for` and link to troubles when you wrote that comment :).

Answer (score 6):

Don't use a [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loop to iterate over arrays. Use a regular ol' [`for`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) loop:

```
for(var i=0; i<dayLists.length; i++) {
  dayListID = "#" + dayLists[i];
  $(dayListID).append("test");
}
```

See for yourself what the difference is: http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/h9hpr/

Comment: Thanks, done that. It still confuses me after having drilled into my head when learning PHP that "foring through arrays is evil, foreaching is good".

Comment: @JJ56 In JavaScript `for .. in` for arrays is like using a nuclear missile to hit a bird. It is slow and you might get a lot of unwanted side-effects.

Comment: @JJ56 now it is time for this to get drilled into your head: ***JavaScript is not PHP.***

Answer (score 2):

You should be using this:

```
dayLists = ["something", "somethingElse"];
for(var i=0; i<dayLists.length; i++){
    $("#" + dayList[i]).append("test");
}
```